# `Unknown` (`Other`) memory leak in Android?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

Android Studio Memory Profiler reports allocations in `Others` category.

[image]

According to https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html: Other: Memory used by your app that the system isn't sure how to categorize.

If we dig deeper, similar memory footprint information can be retrieved at runtime using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.MemoryInfo.html#getMemoryStat(java.lang.String)

It looks like `Others` in Android Studio Memory Profiler corresponds to `summary.private-other` in `Debug.MemoryInfo` class. That parameter is reported as:

```
public int getSummaryPrivateOther() {
            return getTotalPrivateClean()
              + getTotalPrivateDirty()
              - getSummaryJavaHeap()
              - getSummaryNativeHeap()
              - getSummaryCode()
              - getSummaryStack()
              - getSummaryGraphics();
        }
```

Which kind of memory allocations end up in that category? It is obviously not Java, Native, Code, Stack and Graphics.

If my app (with enormously large codebase so I can't really pin point a certain code that causes it) consumes a lot of `Other` memory, is there a certain source/pattern that leads to such consumption?

**Edit 1**
I was able to partially answer the first part my own question:

> Which kind of memory allocations end up in that category? It is
>   obviously not Java, Native, Code, Stack and Graphics.

RAM info can also be retrieved using `adb shell dumpsys meminfo <your proc name>` and typically looks like:

[image]

Experimentally, I can see that `Unknown` is most likely included into  `Private Other`. Which raises the next question: what is `Unknown`? According to https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys.html#meminfo:

> Any RAM pages that the system could not classify into one of
>   the other more specific items. Currently, this contains mostly native
>   allocations, which cannot be identified by the tool when collecting
>   this data due to Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR). Like the
>   Dalvik heap, the Pss Total for Unknown takes into account sharing with
>   Zygote, and Private Dirty is unknown RAM dedicated to only your app.

It looks like it's still native allocations. Identifiable Native allocations end up in `Native` category, however, Native allocations whose data is no longer identifiable due to ASLR seem to end up in `Unknown`.

The main question however still holds:

> If my app (with enormously large codebase so I can't really pin point
>   a certain code that causes it) consumes a lot of `Other` memory, is
>   there a certain source/pattern that leads to such consumption? I'm looking for answers such as hanging threads, open cursors, webviews and etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After many hours of research, I've finally found one common pattern that leads to high `Unknown` memory consumption: `WebView` with enabled `Javascript`.

The following sample code will lead to consuming about `100mb` of `unknown` memory on HTC One API 19 and about `120mb` on Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (API23) and about `94mb` on Samsung Galaxy S8 (API-24):

```
    val webView1 = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview_1)
    webView1.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView1.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.load_webview_1).setOnClickListener {
        webView1.loadUrl("http://www.nbcsports.com/") // can be any arbitrary URL
    }
```

The following command will output `Unknown` memory in kb category every second):

```
while sleep 1; do adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.dkarmazi.memoryleakerapp | grep Unknown; done
```

Output:

[image]

Now it raises a series of follow up questions which go beyond this particular issue:

1. Does OS report WebView memory under `Unknown` in `dumpsys meminfo` on purpose or it's a bug? If it's a bug, is it specific to certain OS and API levels? If it is on purpose, then having 4-5 active `WebView`s will crash the app with very confusing traces.
2. Is such high memory consumption for a modern typical webpage with javascript normal or there is also a bug that is triggered by certain javascript code? Experimentally, simpler sites like `http://stackoverflow.com/` take `23mb`. Pages with a richer user experience, like any news website, will take up to `120mb-130mb`.

**TLDR: `WebView` with enabled `Javascript` is one common use case that leads to consuming a lot of `unknown` memory on certain manufacturers.**

Update 2018-07-23: There is an open issue on chromium bug tracker which is directly connected to this investigation: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=819901

TL;DR: only certain versions of WebView (>52) will cause high memory consumption while older WebViews are fine. The reason remains unknown.

Comment: Thanks for investigation, that's interesting finding!